# In Vuex is it ok to skip actions and commit mutations directly from component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Every time this questions comes up the answer is always the same - actions are for **asynchronicity**. And I know that in future versions of Vuex actions and mutations will be merged.

But hey, I can do asynchronous calls directly from my component methods. For example, why is this considered a bad practice? Asynchronicity is not a problem here. So why do I even need actions?

```
methods:
{
    async fetchTodos()
    {
        this.$store.commit('isLoading', true)

        const result = await Todos.fetchAll()

        this.$store.commit('setTodos', result.data)
        this.$store.commit('isLoading', false)
    }
},
```

Comment: it's not about asynchrony in the code that calls the commit, it's about asynchrony in the actions themselves

Comment: *And I know that in future versions of Vuex actions and mutations will be merged* - any links? It would be a reasonable move but I'm unaware of this. *I can do asynchronous calls directly from my component methods* - technically you can do things that Vuex offers without it. *For example, why is this considered a bad practice?* - it breaks the separation of concerns. Business logic belongs to a store, and presentation to a component. Principles aren't carved in stone and can be broken but in practice this often results in messy code that is hard to test, maintain and reuse.

Comment: @EstusFlask On the merging of actions and mutations: [Vuex 4x roadmap](https://github.com/vuejs/roadmap#vuex-4x)

Comment: If you want to reuse `fetchTodos` in another component, then you'd probably want to make it an action.  If you're using Vuex modules, then actions can also be used to perform mutations in other modules.